# Apache Reverse Proxy with Node JS and Socket IO spawning lots of httpd_prefork processes

Tags: node.js, apache, socket.io, reverse-proxy

I'm attempting to setup a reverse proxy using Apache for my Node JS app, which uses Socket IO (and is written in Koa v1.x).

This works great if I *don't* use Socket IO; but when I do use it, I am running into big issues with Apache spawning lots of http_prefork processes - to such an extent, that it maxes them out (my config is 150), and Apache just hangs forever until I restart it.

My hunch is that Socket IO is keeping the processes open, so when my app gets more than 150 connections, it gets upset and hangs - leading me to believe I am doing something wrong...

Has anyone else experienced the same issue as me, and if so - is it resolvable, or do I simply up the maximum number of prefork processes indefinitely (feels wrong).

I'd normally use Ngnix for reverse proxy - it seems to play nicer in my experience (and I haven't ran into this issue) - but unfortunately, installing it on the server my app is running on is out of the question.

Here's a part of my apache config:

```
ProxyRequests        off
ProxyPreserveHost    on
RewriteEngine        on

RewriteCond         %{QUERY_STRING}     transport=polling           [NC]
RewriteRule         /(.*)               http://localhost:5000/$1    [P]
RewriteCond         %{HTTP:Upgrade}     websocket                   [NC]
RewriteRule         /(.*)               ws://localhost:5000/$1      [P]
ProxyPass           /my-app/            http://localhost:5000/
ProxyPassReverse    /my-app/            http://localhost:5000/

# Redirect to fully-qualified domain name for HTTPS
Redirect permanent  /my-app             https://[fqdn]/my-app/
```

Here's a couple of snippets of my Koa app too and how I use Socket IO.

*I've removed some parts to avoid over complicating, but can include more if required.*

**app.js**

```
'use strict';
const app    = koa();
const server = http.createServer(app.callback()).listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, => {
    console.log('HTTP Server started...');
    const io = require('./io')(server);
});
```

**io.js**

```
module.exports = (server) => {
    const io = require("socket.io")(server);

    // Catch errors
    io.on("error", (err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });

    // On connection
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {

        console.log("[SOCKET IO]: A user has connected with ID:", socket.id);

        // Join a room event with callback emit of 'room-joined'
        socket.on('join-room', (roomName) => {
            console.log(`A user is joining a room with the name ${roomName}`);
            socket.join(roomName);
            socket.emit('room-joined', roomName);
        });

    });
```

Comment: `socket.io`'s preferred transport are WebSockets, which maintain a persistent connection to the server. It seems to me that the `prefork` MPM isn't suitable to handle that, and you should probably look into one of the other MPM's.

Comment: Thanks @robertklep, can you suggest which MPM I could try e.g. Worker?
I'm not an apache wizard - just fumble my way through! I've looked at this post on ServerFault http://serverfault.com/questions/383526/how-do-i-select-which-apache-mpm-to-use, and I'm not sure what I could try. Is Apache not the right choice for what I am trying to do? Thanks again.

Comment: I haven't used Apache myself in ages (I prefer nginx), but looking at that post, I think the `event` MPM is best suited for what you're trying to do.

Comment: please note that using Event MPM has another bad drawback - if any socket.io thread remains "unfinished", the worker will not cease to exist (stop itself) and hangs indefinetly, until apache is fully restarted :( im trying to find my way around this bug/feature now